# Bind a Razor select to a Dictionary from VewData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm writing a web-app with **.NET Core MVC** (**dotnet** version **1.0.4**).

I want to pass a `Dictionary<string, string>` in a `ViewData` object from controller to view and bind it to `<select>` element.

This is a result that I want to get:

[image]

And I tried two ways to achieve it.

### 1st way

#### Controller's code

```
Dictionary<string, string> animals = new Dictionary<string, string>();
animals.Add("1", "cat");
animals.Add("2", "dog");
animals.Add("3", "bunny");

ViewData["animals"] = new SelectList(animals);
```

#### Views's code

```
<select asp-for="Animal_id" asp-items="(SelectList)@ViewData["animals"]" class="form-control"></select>
```

That gives me this result

[image]

### 2nd way

#### Controller's code

```
Dictionary<string, string> animals = new Dictionary<string, string>();
animals.Add("1", "cat");
animals.Add("2", "dog");
animals.Add("3", "bunny");

ViewData["animals"] = new SelectList(animals.Select(r => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = r.Key,
    Value = r.Value
}));
```

#### Views's code

*The same.*

That gives me this result:

[image]

Apparently, something I don't understand about this concept, although I feel like I'm on a right track. Can you please help me - what needs to be done in order to get the result from my first picture (`<option>`s with `value`s)?

Comment: You have your images the wrong way around. And its `ViewData["animals"] = new SelectList(animals. "Key", "Value");` to generate the correct `<option>` elements

Comment: @StephenMuecke, wow, I knew that I was missing just a bit. Works like a charm. Please, add this as an answer and I will mark it as a solution. P.S. Pictures order is fine, what is wrong there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You using the overload of the `SelectList` constructor where the parameter is `IEnumerable`. That overload calls the `.ToString()` method of each item in your collection, and because they are complex objects, you get the results your seeing. That overload is really only useful if your collection was `IEnumerable<string>`.

You need to use the overload that accepts arguments for the `dataValueField` and `dataTextField` which defines the properties to be used for the options value and display text.

```
Dictionary<string, string> animals = new Dictionary<string, string>();
animals.Add("1", "cat");
animals.Add("2", "dog");
animals.Add("3", "bunny");

ViewData["animals"] = new SelectList(animals, "Key", "Value");
```

Note also in your 2nd example, you have already generated an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` To use `new SelectList(...)` to create an identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one is pointless extra ovehead and it can just be

```
ViewData["animals"] = animals.Select(r => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = r.Key,
    Value = r.Value
}));
```

and in the view `asp-items="(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewData["animals"]"`

Answer (score 2):

With your current code, you are creating a `SelectList` but not specifying what should be the data value field and data text field (of the collection you are using).

You can use the SelectList overload which takes those 2 params.

```
ViewData["animals"] = new SelectList(animals.Select(r => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = r.Key.ToString(),
    Text = r.Value
}),"Value","Text");
```

But that is unnecessary code we are executing. You alreay are creating a list of SelectListItem (to pass to SelectList).You should simply use that collection to build the select element.

```
var animals = new Dictionary<string, string>();
animals.Add("1", "cat");
animals.Add("2", "dog");
animals.Add("3", "bunny");

ViewData["animals"] = animals.Select(r => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = r.Key.ToString(),
    Text = r.Value
});
```

And in your view

```
<select asp-for="SomePropertyName" 
                    asp-items="@(ViewData["animals"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)">

</select>
```

If you use ViewBag instead of ViewData, You do not need the explicit casting.

```
ViewBag.AnimalList= animals.Select(r => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = r.Key.ToString(),
    Text = r.Value
});
```

and

```
<select asp-for="Name" asp-items="@ViewBag.AnimalList">
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, that works. Although `ViewBag` creates a correct `<select>`, and `ViewData` "confuses" value and text :) but I got the principle. Thank you.

Comment: You were setting the Key of dictionary item(the Id value) to the Text of SelectListItem.  I have it in the correct form(value=key, text=value(of dictionary item))